# MySQL : Memory allocation issue

Tags: php, mysql, excel, symfony, wamp

I'm using WAMP on my computer, and when I run an algorithm that imports data from an Excel file, it just takes too long. In the first place, it throws me an error that there's not enough memory. Then, I extended the `memory_limit`parameter on `php.ini`. But then again, this time, it runs for a long time, then it just shows the famous "Page Cannot Be Displayed" (connection aborted).

Besides, this algorithm has to import only 5 rows. But it's a bit long. It creates objects based on the values it gets from the Excel file, and stuf..

So, what do you think ?

N.B : I'm using Symfony2, Doctrine2 and the library PHPExcel that helps manipulating Excel-like files.

**Edit (here's the code) :**

```
<?php

public function bachelierAction(){

        $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
        $inputFileName = 'Excel_Files/Bacheliers/Bacheliers12.xlsx';


        /**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
        $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        /**  Define how many rows we want to read for each "chunk"  **/
        $chunkSize = 1;
        /**  Create a new Instance of our Read Filter  **/
        $chunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter();

        /**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter  **/
        $objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

        // The Entity Manager :
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $anneObj = new Annee();
        $anneObj->setAnnee(2012);


        for ($startRow = 2; $startRow <= 6 ; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
            /*  Tell the Read Filter which rows we want this iteration  */
            $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow,$chunkSize);
            /**  Load only the rows that match our filter  **/
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);

            // Extraire les données du bachelier :
            $cne = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$startRow)->getValue();
            $nom = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$startRow)->getValue();
            $prenom = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$startRow)->getValue();
            $sexe = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,$startRow)->getValue();;
            $dateNaissance = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,$startRow)->getValue();

            // Création du bachelier
            $bachelier = new Bachelier();
            $bachelier->setCne($cne)
                      ->setDateNaissance($dateNaissance)
                      ->setNom($nom)
                      ->setPrenom($prenom)
                      ->setSexe($sexe);

            $em->persist($bachelier);


            // Extraire les données du bac :
            $moyenneBac = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10,$startRow)->getValue();
            $typeBac = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8,$startRow)->getValue();
            $sessionBac = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(13,$startRow)->getValue();
            $mentionBac = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11,$startRow)->getValue();
            $etabBac = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(14,$startRow)->getValue();


            $typeBacObj = $em->getRepository('PFASIGBundle:TypeBac')->find($typeBac);
            $sessionBacObj = $em->getRepository('PFASIGBundle:SessionBac')->find($sessionBac);
            $mentionBacObj = $em->getRepository('PFASIGBundle:MentionBac')->find($mentionBac);
            $etabBacObj = $em->getRepository('PFASIGBundle:EtablissementBac')->find($etabBac);

            // Création de l'établissement du Bac
            if($etabBacObj == null ){
                // Type de l'établissement du Bac
                $typeEtabBac = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(16,$startRow)->getValue();
                $typeEtabBacObj = $em->getRepository('PFASIGBundle:TypeEtablissementBac')->find($typeEtabBac);

                // La délégation de l'établissement du Bac
                $delegBac = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(19,$startRow)->getValue();
                $delegBacObj = $em->getRepository('PFASIGBundle:Delegation')->find($delegBac);

                $etabBacObj = new EtablissementBac();
                $etabBacLibelle = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(15,$startRow)->getValue();

                $etabBacObj->setCodeLieu($etabBac)
                           ->setNomLieu($etabBacLibelle)
                           ->setDelegation($delegBac)
                           ->setTypeEtabBac($typeEtabBac);

                $em->persist($etabBacObj);

            }

            // Création du bac
            $bac = new Bac();
            $bac->setAnneeBac($anneObj)
                ->setBachelier($bachelier)
                ->setEtabBac($etabBacObj)
                ->setMentionBac($mentionBacObj)
                ->setMoyenne($moyenneBac)
                ->setSessionBac($sessionBac)
                ->setTypeBac($typeBacObj);

            $em->persist($bac);

        }


        $msg = "Les " + $startRow + " bacheliers ont été importés avec succès.";

        try{
            $em->flush();

        }catch(\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e){
            $msg = "Les données n'ont pas pu être importées ! Une erreur est survenue !";

        }

        return $this->render('PFASIGBundle:Carte:bachelier.html.twig',array('msg' => $msg));

    }
```

**EDIT 2 :**
After applying recommandations from Mark, here's the code just to test :

```
public function bachelierAction(){

        $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
        $inputFileName = 'Excel_Files/Bacheliers/Bacheliers12.xlsx';

        // Cell caching ::
        $cacheMethod = \PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_apc;
        $cacheSettings = array( 'cacheTime' => 600);
        \PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);


        /**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
        $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        /**  Define how many rows we want to read for each "chunk"  **/
        $chunkSize = 1;
        /**  Create a new Instance of our Read Filter  **/
        $chunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter();

        /**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter  **/
        $objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

        // The Entity Manager :
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $anneObj = new Annee();
        $anneObj->setAnnee(2012);


        for ($startRow = 2; $startRow <= 6 ; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
            /*  Tell the Read Filter which rows we want this iteration  */
            $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow,$chunkSize);
            /**  Load only the rows that match our filter  **/
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);

            // Extraire les données du bachelier :
            list( ,$cne,$nom,$prenom, ,$sexe,$dateNaissance) = $sheet->rangeToArray('A'.$startRow.':F'.$startRow);
        }

        return $this->render('PFASIGBundle:Carte:bachelier.html.twig',array('msg' => $cne));

    }
```

Unfortunately, I still get the error :
`FatalErrorException: Error: Allowed memory size of 157286400 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 111967106 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\symf_PFA_v1\vendor\codeplex\phpexcel\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php line 428`

For the record, in my php.ini, I got :

`memory_limit=150M`
`apc.shm_size=180M`

**EDIT 3 :** : Here's the current code (enhanced)

```
public function bachelierAction(){

        $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
        $inputFileName = 'myfile.xlsx';

        // Cell caching ::
        $cacheMethod = \PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_apc;
        $cacheSettings = array( 'cacheTime' => 600);
        \PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);

        /**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
        $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        /**  Define how many rows we want to read for each "chunk"  **/
        $chunkSize = 10;
        /**  Create a new Instance of our Read Filter  **/
        $chunkFilter = new chunkReadFilter();

        /**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter  **/
        $objReader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);


        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

for ($startRow = 2; $startRow <= 6 ; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
            /*  Tell the Read Filter which rows we want this iteration  */
            $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow,$chunkSize);
            /**  Load only the rows that match our filter  **/
            $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

            $result = $sheet->rangeToArray('A'.$startRow.':G'.$startRow);
            list( ,$cne,$nom,$prenom, ,$sexe,$dateNaissance) = $result[0];

            // some process
            $result = $sheet->rangeToArray('I'.$startRow.':O'.$startRow);
            list($typeBac,,$moyenneBac,$mentionBac,,$sessionBac,$etabBac) = $result[0]; 

            // some process

        }
                // render the Twig template
}
```

the class **chunkReadFilter** :

```
namespace Me\MyBundle\Entity;

/**  Define a Read Filter class 
 * implementing PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter  */


class chunkReadFilter implements \PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter 
{ 
    private $_startRow = 0; 
    private $_endRow   = 0; 

    /**  Set the list of rows that we want to read  */ 
    public function setRows($startRow, $chunkSize) { 
        $this->_startRow = $startRow; 
        $this->_endRow   = $startRow + $chunkSize; 
    } 

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') { 
        //  Only read the heading row, and the configured rows 
        if (($row == 1) ||
            ($row >= $this->_startRow && $row < $this->_endRow)) { 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: "*So, what do you think ?*" - I think it might help if you showed us the "algorithm" that you're using.  "*It creates objects based on the values it gets from the Excel file, and stuf..*" is hardly sufficient detail for anyone to form the slightest clue.

Comment: I have edited my post, and put the code.

Comment: check path file if it is true. and what does `2012` mean?

Comment: `2012` means the year (it's an integer)

Comment: PHPExcel is known for a high demand of memory. You'll find many posts dealing with this issue, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251459/phpexcel-memory-problems-any-more-ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Observation #1**

Take advantage of PHPExcel's rangeToArray() method instead of reading each cell individually using getCellByColumnAndRow().

e.g.

```
list ($cne, $nom, $prenom, , $sexe, $dateNaissance) = 
    $sheet->rangeToArray('A'.$startRow.':F'.$startRow);
```

**Observation #2**

Use cell caching in preference to chunking via a read filter, that way you're not constantly re-reading the whole file for every chunk, but still saving memory

**Observation #3**

Alternatively, use a slightly higher chunk size than 1 row at a time. If you have 100 rows, then you need to reread the whole file 100 times; set chunk size to 10 and you only have to reread it 10 times; set it as high as memory will allow.

**Observation #4**

Combine observations #1, #2 and #3 with a bit of experimentation to see what chunk size and caching methods give you the best balance of memory and speed.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the observations. I applied the observation #1. Concerning the chunk, I just want to see if it'll work for 5 rows or 10. Now, it doesn't even for that small number. So, I'm still keeping the chunk at 1.
For the memory, I still have a problem. I really have no idea how to deal with it. So, please help me. I don't know how to configure "the cell caching".

Comment: There's a whole section of the developer documentation devoted to cell caching: section 4.2.1, entitled "Cell Caching"

Comment: Mark, would you please take a look at my edit #2 above. Thank you.

Comment: I've no idea where your memory is going. How many rows, how many columns in your worksheets? Are you limiting the columns you load with the read filter? You haven't shown the filter at all. Try limiting the load to just the worksheets you need. Unset the Reader after the load.

Comment: I only have 1 worksheet in my Excel file. It's about 220.000 rows and 30 columns.
Actually, I need to load all the columns (well, I don't need 4 or 5 of them). And please, what do you mean by "You haven't shown the filter at all." How do I unset the reader ?
I really appreciate your help, Mark.

Comment: I mean, where is your chunkReadFilter class defined, what does it contain.

Comment: How do you unset the reader? Forget I said that, because you need it for every loop

Comment: Okay, the class chunkReadFilter is correct, I guess, I already tested the same code for a small Excel file (~ 24 Ko), and it works. The problem is when I use my big Excel file (13 Mo), it throws the exception "Fatal Error :.."
Take a look at Edit 3. I'll put the class chuckReadFilter

Comment: You might consider restricting the column within the chunkReadFilter check as well